# Continuous surjective mapping from half-open interval to the reals / the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis

1) Is there a continuous surjective mapping of $(0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ ?

To me it seems not, but haven't been able to prove why it is false though. I was thinking of finding compact sets contained in (0, 1], and having the right endpoint fixed, e.g $[\frac{1}{2} ,1]$ $[\frac{1}{3}, 1]$, $[\frac{1}{4}, 1]$ etc. But then not sure if this is the right approach or what to do after this.

2) Is there a continuous surjective mapping of $(0, 1]$ to the Cantor Set ?

Again to me it seems not true because Cantor Set is Hausdorff space (to be precise it is Stone space) and we know that the pre-image of continuous functions should conserve compactness if we are mapping to a Hausdorff space, and Cantor Set is compact, but is there any other way to prove this without talking about Hausdorff space or compactness of the Cantor Set?

Comment: 1) consider that the answer is true!. you have to think of function that does not have limit at $0$ and go crazy there...

Comment: Compact Hausdorff is not an obstacle for 2). Take, for instance, the compact Hausdorff interval $[\frac12, 1]$. You can map into that interval nicely by mapping the upper half of $(0, 1]$ via $x\mapsto x$, and the lower half via $x\mapsto 1-x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 1) consider $\frac{1}{x} \sin\frac{1}{x}$

2) is false since the image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected.